# Return data from an ajax call whose type is POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that is of type post and I want to return the data by way of using return.

I have tried:

```
function GetDataById(Id){
    return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify({ ID: Id }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                return data;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                
            }
        });
}
```

and I have tried:

```
function GetDataById(Id){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify({ ID: Id }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                return data;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                
            }
        });
}
```

and what I am doing is:

```
(function(){
    const data = GetDataById(208);
    console.log(data);
})();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `return` returns from the `function` it's within - in your case, that's `success:function()..` *not* the outer `GetDataById`.  See linked question/answer for a lot more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.ajax()` returns a promise. If you want to implement a function that gets the data after the call, you can simply return `$.ajax()` call and use promise's then and catch instead.

```
function GetDataById(Id){
    return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify({ ID: Id }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });
}

(function(){
    GetDataById(208).then(data => console.log(data));
})();
```

Comment: This put where I needed to be and used async await. Thanks for the direction